# What's a good way to make a PHP website approach the database object oriented?

Tags: php, mysql, oop

*Please note I'm not looking for 'use a framework' answers. I'm trying to structurally improve the way I code websites and approach databases from PHP.*

I'm building a web service from scratch, without any frameworks. I'm using a LAMP stack and am trying to learn a bit of PHP's OO functionality while I'm at it. I've previously only used OO to make mobile apps.

I've been at it for months now (as planned, no worries). Along the way I've bumped into a couple of structural problems, making me wonder what the best way would be to make the code object oriented.

Pretty much all of the problems involve the database in some way. Say we have a class `DB` and a class `User`. In most cases I only need to fetch a single user's information from the database. I thought a good way to handle it was to have a global `$_db` variable and have the `User` object query the database like so (oversimplified):

```
class User {
    function __construct($id) {
        global $_db;
        $q = $_db->query("SELECT name, mail FROM user WHERE id = ?", $id);
        $this->loadProperties($q);
    }
}
```

Now say we have a page that shows a list of users. I still want to make `User` objects for each of them, but I don't want to query the database for each separate user.

So, I extend the `User` class to take an object as an argument:

```
class User {
    function __construct($id) {
        if(is_object($id))
            $q = $id;
        else {
            global $_db;
            $q = $_db->query("SELECT name, mail FROM user WHERE id = ?", $id);
        }

        $this->loadProperties($q);
    }
}
```

Now I can create a list of, for example, the 100 most recently created and active accounts:

```
$user_list = [];

$q = $_db->query("SELECT name, mail FROM user WHERE banned = 0 ORDER BY date_created DESC LIMIT 100");

while($a = $_db->fetch($q))
    $user_list[] = new User($a);
```

This all works great, except for one big downside: the database queries for table `user` are no longer in one place, which is kind of making spaghetti code. This is where I'm starting to wonder whether this can be done more efficiently.

So maybe I need to extend my `DB` object instead of my `User` object, for example:

```
class DB {
    public function getUsers($where) {
        $q = $this->query("SELECT name, mail FROM user WHERE ".$where);

        $users = [];
        while($a = $this->fetch($q))
            $users[] = new User($a);
    }
}
```

Now I would create the user list as follows:

```
$user_list = $_db->getUsers("banned = 0 ORDER BY date_created DESC LIMIT 100");
```

But now I'm calling the `getUsers()` method in various places using various SQL queries, solving nothing. I also don't want to load the same properties each time, so my `getUsers()` method will have to take entire SQL queries as an argument. Anyway, you get the point.

Speaking of loading different properties, there's another thing that has been bugging me writing OO in PHP. Let's assume our PHP object has at least every property our database row has. Say I have a method `User::getName()`:

```
class User {
    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

This function will assume the appropriate field has been loaded from the database. However it would be inefficient to preload all of the user's properties each time I make an object. Sometimes I'll only need the user's name. On the other hand it would also be inefficient to go into the database at this point to load this one property.

I have to make sure that for each method I use, the appropriate properties have already been loaded. This makes complete sense from a performance perspective, but from an OO perspective, it means you have to know beforehand which methods you're gonna use which makes it a lot less dynamic and, again, allows for spaghetti code.

The last thing I bumped into (for now at least), is how to separate actual **new** users from `new User`. I figured I'd use a separate class called `Registration` (again, oversimplified):

```
class Registration {
    function createUser() {
        $form = $this->getSubmittedForm();

        global $_db;
        $_db->query("INSERT INTO user (name, mail) VALUES (?, ?)", $form->name, $form->mail);
        if($_db->hasError)
            return FALSE;

        return $_db->insertedID;
    }
}
```

But this means I have to create two separate classes for each database table and again I have different classes accessing the same table. Not to mention there's a third class handling login sessions that's also accessing the user table.

In summary, I feel like all of the above can be done way more efficiently. Most importantly I want pretty code. I feel like I'm missing a way to approach the database from an OO perspective. But how can I do so without losing the dynamics and power of SQL queries?

I'm looking forward to reading your experiences and ideas in this field.

**Update**

Seems most of you condemn my use of `global $_db`. Though you've convinced me this isn't the best approach, for the scope of this question it's irrelevant whether I'm supplying the database through an argument, a global or a singleton. It's still a separate class `DB` that handles any interaction with the database.

Comment: Step 1. Avoid `global`.

Comment: Step 2. Read about [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)

Comment: @cwallenpoole I don't think `global` is to be avoided entirely. How else would different objects be able to access the logged in user's information?

Comment: @Robbert There are a number of ways. Since you're using OOP, you might have a Singleton which manages that, or at the least a method with a static variable.

Comment: @Robbert At a minimum, wrapping your DB variable in a class or function means that it is impossible to accidentally re-assign later, which is an extraordinarily good thing.

Comment: @Robbert As far as the current user's information: you probably should take a look and see how most libraries manage that. Even Drupal and WordPress keep that value hidden inside of wrapping objects.

Comment: @cwallenpoole can you elaborate in an actual answer? I've worked with WordPress for years, it's a bad example. They use a lot of spaghetti and procedural code and a global $WP_Query for their main query.

Comment: @Robbert I'm not saying that WP is a paragon of virtue (some of their code is downright awful), just that the current user is wrapped in a function: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user.

Comment: Even if you don't use a framework, you should learn one (or a few). It will help show you how others have solved these problems. It's PHP so you can dig into the source to see how they implement things. I've recommended `Symfony2` (or `Silex`) below, but there are many others with useful paradigms.

Comment: @cwallenpoole I appreciate your help, but `wp_get_current_user` does nothing but return a global variable: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php. The wrapper is useless if the global gets overwritten. I'd like to see you expand on the 'don't use `global`' idea though.

Comment: @Robbert As I said, some of the code is downright awful.

Comment: @Robbert As to "why not globals", you can find plenty of information about that online, but here is one site which does a decent job of explaining. http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad

Comment: I'm convinced @cwallenpoole. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a common thing to have a separate class to handle SQL queries and to keep the fetched data. In fact, it is the real application of the Single Responsibility Principle.

What I usually do is keep a class with all the information concerning the data, in your case the User class, with all the user information as fields.

Then comes the business layer, for instance UserDataManager (though the use of "Manager" as a suffix is not recommended and you'd better find a more suitable name in each scenario) which takes the pdo object in its constructor to avoid use of global variables and has all the SQL methods. You'd thus have methods registerNewUser, findUserById, unsuscribeUser and so on (the use of "User" in the method can be implied by the class name and be omitted).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Simple but effective. I love it. In this setup, how would you go about retrieving information of the logged in user? Would it have its own class `LoggedInUser`? If so, if a logged in user updates his profile, which class would handle form processing?

Comment: I think overestimating the logged in user is as bad a mistake as overestimating the db connection to make it a singleton (see my comments on Jérémy's answer). You just have to think that a logged in user is to be handled like any other user, and you pass it anywhere it is needed. You have a getRank() method ? Pass the user. You have a canReadPrivateMessage ? Pass the user. A logged in user is a user, so updateProfile belongs to UserDataManager. Surely you won't need to fetch other user's passwords, so what ?

Comment: Makes perfect sense, I'm convinced. I've marked this as best answer. I know this question has many different answers, but I like how you summed up a very solid solution in just a few lines.

Comment: As long as you're satisfied with my way of doing things, then I'm glad I could help. If I may, this is also a very interesting topic : http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontNameClassesObjectManagerHandlerOrData

Answer (score 2):

I've liked to use the [data mapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) pattern (or at least I think that's how I'm doing it). I've done this for some sites built on [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/documentation), though it's applicable to going without a framework since Silex is very lightweight and doesn't impose much on how you architect your code. In fact, I recommend you check out Symfony2/Silex just to get some ideas for ways to design your code.

Anyway, I've used classes like `UserMapper`. Since I was using the [Doctrine DBAL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/index.html) library, I used Dependency injection to give each mapper a `$db`. But the DBAL is pretty much a wrapper on the `PDO` class as far as I understand, so you could inject that instead.

Now you have a `UserMapper` who is responsible for the CRUD operations. So I solve your first problem with methods like `LoadUser($id)` and `LoadAllUsers()`. Then I would set all the properties on the `new User` based on the data from the database. You can similarly have `CreateUser(User $user)`. Note that in "create", I'm really passing a `User` object and mapping it to the database. You could call it `PersistUser(User $user)` to make this distinction more clear. Now all of the SQL queries are in one place and your `User` class is just a collection of data. The `User` doesn't need to come from the database, you could create test users or whatever else without any modification. All of the persistence of `User is encapsulated in another class.

I'm not sure that it's **always** bad to load all of the properties of a user, but if you want to fix that, it's not hard to make `LoadUsername($id)` or other methods. Or you could do `LoadUser($id, array $properties)` with a set of properties taht you want to load. If your naming is consistent, then it's easy to have set the properties like:

```
// in a foreach, $data is the associative array returned by your SQL
$setter = 'set'.$property;
$user->$setter($data[$property]);
```

Or (and?) you could solve this with Proxy objects. I haven't done this, but the idea is to return a bunch of `UserProxy` objects, which extend `User`. But they have the `Mapper` injected and they override the `get`ters to call into the `Mapper` to select more. Perhaps when you access one property on a proxy, it will `select` everything via the mapper (a method called `populateUser($id)`?) and then subsequent `get`ters can just access the properties in memory. This might make some sense if you, for example, select all users then need to access data on a subset. But I think in general it may be easier to select everything.

```
public function getX()
{
    if (!isset($this->x)) {
        $this->mapper->populateUser($this);
    }
    return $this->x;
}
```

For new users, I say just do `$user = new User...` and set everything up, then call into `$mapper->persist($user)`. You can wrap that up in another class, like `UserFactory->Create($data)` and it can return the (persisted) `User`. Or that class can be called `Registration` if you'd like.

Did I mention you should use `Dependency Injection` to handle all of these services (like the `Mappers` and others like `Factories` maybe)? Maybe just grab the DIC from Silex, called [Pimple](http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/). Or implement a lightweight one yourself (it's not hard).

I hope this helps. It's a high-level overview of some things I've picked up from writing a lot of PHP and using Syfmony2/Silex. Good luck and glad to see PHP programmers like yourself actually trying to "do things right"! Please comment if I can elaborate anywhere. Hope this answer helps you out.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Matt, it goes to show there's still so much for me to learn. My main concern is minimizing the number of SQL queries and the number of loaded fields per object, so I like the idea of having a single object with methods that load different fields for different views (`getUserByID`, `getUserProfile`, etc). I'm to deep in this project to move it to any framework, but for a next project I'll definitely have another look at your suggestions.

Comment: Like I said, you don't need to move to a framework necessarily, but you should learn how others have solved common problems. But if you do want to use a framework for your next project, Silex is nice because it is helpful without forcing too many conventions on you. But it handles things like routing very nicely. There are other "micro" frameworks like that but I'm not familiar with them. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You should first begin by writing a class as a wrapper to your Database object, which would be more clean that a global variable (read about the Singleton Pattern if you don't know it, and there is a lot of examples of Singleton Database Wrapper on the web). You'll then have a better view of the architecture you should implement.

Best is to separate datas from transactions with the database, meaning that you can for example have two classes for your User ; one that will only send queries and fetch responses, and the other that will manage datas thanks to object's attributes and methods. Sometimes, there can be also some action that doesn't require to interact with the database, and that would be implemented in these classes too.

Last but not least, it can be a good idea to look a MVC frameworks and how they work (even if you don't want to use it) ; that would give you a good idea of how can be structured a web application, and how to implement these pattern for you in some way.

Comment: I'm not sure using a singleton anti-pattern is much better than having a global db variable.

Comment: @Arlaud Agbe Pierre Could you please synthethize why?

Comment: Singleton are an anti-pattern. They make you feel good about yourself because you're using a class instead of global variables but they have the same flaws.

If you're really interested, I would recommend the first 6 notes on this page :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#cite_note-1

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions Jérémy. Regarding singletons: whether I'm using a global or something else, I still have a single `DB` object (as noted in my question) that handles the PDO. It wasn't the focus of the question.